# When kubernetes deployment is deleted, ReplicaSets are not being deleted

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, kubernetes-deployment

I am using kubernetes version: **1.25.8**.
I have a yaml to create a deployment with 2 pods of nginx. When I apply the yaml (kubecl apply), it creates below resources:
1 Deployment
1 ReplicaSet
2 Pods.

When I delete the yaml (kubectl delete) , deployment is deleted but replicaSet and pods are still there.

**Note:** I also tried **spec.revisionHistoryLimit** but it works only when I update the deployment with some change (for example nginx version) but on deployment deletion, replicaSets and pods are still there.

This behaviour is causing problem, lets say if I delete and re-create deployment four times with different nginx versions.  There are 4 replicas set and each one is creating 2 pods (total 8) with different versions.